# Safely redirect old Wordpress blog links to new WP blog

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, seo, http-status-code-301

I have two Wordpress blogs on the same domain, (one called 'News' and another called 'Blog')

I am moving across all the content from the 'News' blog to the 'Blog' blog but I need to setup the 301 redirects correctly to not damage anything from an SEO perspective.

The old news link as as follows:

```
www.site.com/news/this-is-my-post-name-3413
```

The new link for the same post now it has been moved will appear like this

```
www.site.com/blog/this-is-the-post-name
```

Can anyone explain how I would correctly setup the htaccess 301 redirects to tell Google to redirect all the old **"news"** content to the new **"blog"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best bet would be to use plugins. There is a plugin for almost anything in Wordpress. Try using this plugin - It has many downloads and good user reviews:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/

Comment: That works pretty well Dave thanks - do you know if I can use some form of regular expressions with this?
I only ask because the 'old' blog has around 1000 posts - i'd rather use some 'global' regular expression if possible than do each post one by one (that will serious do some damage to my Copy & Paste shortcut keys lol)

Comment: hey I don't know...You can go look on the plugin details on wordpress or even look at the reviews and support Q&A - Im sure someone there has asked a similar question

Comment: no probs - thanks for the advice though i'll put the question as answered as I appreciate your efforts & check out the Q&A for the WP plugin :)

Comment: Cool man. I will leave this thread open...for if you would like to ask something else I might be able to answer..Another way I will do it is to just migrate everything by using the import/export tool in wordpress(See under tools). Or, alternatively, if you are comfortable with Databases, export your current DB to the the new DB for the new blog, and just edit the wp_options file in the db to correct all the links to point to the new url...You can do a find/replace to edit mutliple links. But doing this manually, you will still need to set up 301 redirects in your htaccess file for google

Comment: I have come across the following mod rewrite  which 'should' work according to RegExpr (app for making regex) but doesn't quite work

RedirectMatch 301 ^/news/(.+?)(-[0-9]+)?$ /blog/$1

It redirects BUT it still shows the numbers at the end in the new 'blog' the new rule needs to remove this last 'id' at the end.

Comment: See the following Post - Good read: http://forwardjump.com/blog/migrating-website-wordpress-guide/

Comment: Thanks for the post Dave! I eventually fixed it with the following the htaccess 
RedirectMatch  ^/news/(.+?)(-[0-9]+)(/)?$ /blog/$1

Thanks to @JonLin